# how to override self invoked function in javascript in browser console?

Tags: javascript, function, browser-console

Suppose we get to a site and in its scripts has the Self-Executing Anonymous Function like this:

```
(function(){
    var item = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerText = String(++item);
    console.log("this is test");
    },5000)
})();
```

and i want to override it by browser console to something like this:

```
(function(){
    var item = 1;
    /*setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerText = String(++item);
    console.log("this is test");
    },5000)*/
})();
```

(or delete it)... this is possible for regular function that have name but when
i try it for Self-Executing Anonymous Function , a new function created and doesn't override anything...how can i override it?

Comment: Other than editing file and saving it in the console, there is not much you can do.

Comment: @epascarello it is not my site(project), it is a website in www.

Comment: So you can edit it in the console in the Sources Tab

Comment: @epascarello in which browser? i try it in firefox and chrome and they havent option for do that

Comment: Chrome... Click on the file in source, click on the code, start typing, save it

Comment: @epascarello my chrome version is 56.0.2924.87 and doesn't have this feature!!?

Comment: @sami What's the problem you want to solve by overriding the function in a foreign website?

Comment: @bergi i need change algorithm of an online web game but gaining this ability is useful for every one...

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and then messing with local variables. I don't think it's possible to overwrite function expressions.